# Benefits of using EventHandler

Tags: vb.net, oop, events

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around Events and their Handlers in general. I was working from some sample code that used them, and I can't understand why use an event rather than simply using a sub. I'm absolutely sure I'm missing the bigger picture here.

Abbreviated code example:

```
Public Class MenuEntry
    Public Event selected as EventHandler(of EventArgs)

    Protected Friend Overridable Sub onSelectEntry(e as EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent selected(Me, e)
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class Menu
    Private menuSelect as New inputAction(Keys.Enter)
    Private menuEntry as New List(of MenuEntry)

    'keeps track of which menu item we're currently on
    Private _selectedEntry as Integer

    Public Sub Update()
        If menuSelect.evaluate Then
            onSelectEntry(_selectedEntry)
        End If

        Protected Overridable Sub onSelectEntry(ByVal entryIndex as Integer)
            menuEntry(entryIndex).onSelectEntry(New EventArgs())
        End Sub
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class OptionsMenu
    Inherits Menu

    Private arbitraryOne as Integer
    Private arbitraryTwo as Integer

    Public Sub New()
        Dim entryOne as New MenuEntry(String)
        Dim entryTwo as New MenuEntry(String)

        AddHandler entryOne.selected, AddressOf entryOneSelected
        AddHandler entryTwo.selected, AddressOf entryTwoSelected

        MenuEntry.add(entryOne)
        MenuEntry.add(entryTwo)
    End Sub

    Private Sub entryOneSelected(ByVal entryIndex as Integer)
        arbitraryOne += 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub entryTwoSelected(ByVal entryIndex as Integer)
        arbitraryTwo += 1
    End Sub
End Class
```

And I was right, I was missing the bigger picture. Writing out all the code in the same place helped me to see exactly what was going on. Hopefully I'm correct:

The Event allows a class to say 'Do something when this happens' in a very ambiguous way, leaving the class which created the Object to define a Handler; what that action should be. That Handler can, and very likely will, be unique to each instance of the class.

It seems to me that this would likely be achievable (on a basic level) through indexing and enumeration, but that would get messy and become a lot of code to write rather quickly. This is probably a much more flexible and extensible way of handling things.

I'm going to post this anyway, in the hopes that I'll get someone to tell me whether I am correct in my observations or totally off base, and that it helps someone else who is having trouble with this concept as they dip their toes into OOP and event driven objects.

Comment: You put a `Button` on your form. How do you tell when it's clicked without an event?

Comment: Well, I'm not coding a windows form, to start. And the question was more philosophical in nature than anything. But in response to your comment, the program is aware of the click whenever it raises the event. What I failed to realize was that the event could be customized based on who owns the object. It's not really a question of knowing IF the button was clicked, but HOW to handle it.

Comment: I know, it's just hypothetical. That's what they can be used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being able to have arbitrary code being run when the event is raised is an important aspect.  But there's a much bigger benefit, it strongly reduces the coupling between classes.  Note that your MenuEntry class has no reference to the Menu class at all.  You can completely redesign the Menu class and not have a need to make any changes at all in the MenuEntry class.  That makes code  highly composable.

The technical term is the Observer Pattern.  The [Gang of Four book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_%28book%29) is essential reading for programmers.

Comment: Excellent recommendation, I just ordered myself a copy after reading it's description and history. That's exactly the type of practice and approach that excites me... writing code in such an abstract way that I can use it for a variety of applications that have even a minimal relationship. I've been working on creating about a dozen independent 'engines' that can interact with each other, but do not need to, so that I have a framework to develop my actual goal. Thanks again for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your observations are correct. Events are used to let all interested parties know that something has occurred and, if they are interested, they can then perform some additional actions that are not necessarily intrinsic to the class that raised the event.